# Reversing an array and filling in the gaps using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So we have an array of data which has incrementing percentage values with some missing gaps.

So for example

```
  {
    "months": 11,
    "factor": 1.31,
    "upperMonths": 10.5,
    "lowerMonths": 11.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 8
  },
  {
    "months": 10,
    "factor": 1.3,
    "upperMonths": 9.5,
    "lowerMonths": 10.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 9
  },
  {
    "months": 8,
    "factor": 1.28,
    "upperMonths": 7.5,
    "lowerMonths": 8.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 10
  },
  {
    "months": 7,
    "factor": 1.27,
    "upperMonths": 6.5,
    "lowerMonths": 7.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 12
  }
```

Notice that percentage 11 is missing...

So we have got a function which basically loops through the array and fills any missing percentages with the data from the object above so percentage 11 will hole the data from percentage 10 as a duplicate.

http://jsfiddle.net/guideveloper/xnaqtq9y/11/

Our problem is that we need to reverse the array and do the same so now percentage 12 will be the first object and then it will loop through the array and fill in the gaps in reverse so our final object will be something like

```
  {
    "months": 7,
    "factor": 1.27,
    "upperMonths": 6.5,
    "lowerMonths": 7.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 12
  },
  {
    "months": 7,
    "factor": 1.27,
    "upperMonths": 6.5,
    "lowerMonths": 7.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 11
  },
  {
    "months": 8,
    "factor": 1.28,
    "upperMonths": 7.5,
    "lowerMonths": 8.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 10
  },
  {
    "months": 10,
    "factor": 1.3,
    "upperMonths": 9.5,
    "lowerMonths": 10.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 9
  },
  {
    "months": 11,
    "factor": 1.31,
    "upperMonths": 10.5,
    "lowerMonths": 11.49,
    "limit": 20,
    "percentage": 8
  }
```

Then we need to reverse it back again.

Any ideas??

Comment: Theres a reverse() function for arrays, is there anything else to do when reversing?

Comment: Yeah so if you take a look at my fiddle youll see that we have a function which loops through the array and fills in the missing percentage values and duplicates the data from the object before it...

Comment: This works as it stands in the correct order but the reason for reversing it is because we want the missing percentages to be filled with the values above it so if the first object was 19 then the next 16 then 18, 17 would take the data from 19 etc

Comment: So after you filled the gaps in whichever range you got, you want to create percentages down to 0%, right?

Comment: not down to 0% down to the lowest value in the initial array so in my fiddle you'll see the data has the first percentage value at 8 down to 19 so when we reverse that we get 19 to 8 then fill in the gaps so we have 19, 18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8

Comment: i am a bit confused. if you have the row `1, _, 3, 4, _, 6, _, 8, _, 10, _` what do you fill in the gaps? the value of `x[n] = x[n+1]` or `x[n] = x[n-1]`? the approach to reverse and reverse is very uncommon.

Comment: so the fiddle as it stands fills in the gaps with the data from the object before it so 1, 2 uses the data from 1, 3, 4, 5 uses the data from 4, 6, 7 uses the data from 6 etc etc

Comment: but we basically want it to work as it does but to use the data in reverse so  10, 9, 8 uses data from 9 7, 6, 5, 4 uses data from 5 3, 2, 1 uses data from 2

Comment: can one gap get the data from more items? i do not get the catch.

Comment: Ok so i have created a new fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/guideveloper/whasgrfL/1/ which shows a function that works if the array increments but doest work if the array decrements

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the array twice using [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
test.reverse()
```

Comment: Yeah we added reverse(); and reversed the array but the function doesnt fill the gaps and duplicate then object data from the one above...
` function fillArray(arr) {
    var i = 1;
    while (i < test.length) {
        if ((test[i]["percentage"] * 1 - test[i - 1]["percentage"] * 1) > 1) {
            test.splice(i, 0, { "percentage": test[i-1].percentage+1, "factor": test[i - 1]["factor"], "upperMonths": test[i - 1]["upperMonths"], "lowerMonths": test[i - 1]["lowerMonths"], "limit": test[i - 1]["limit"], "months": test[i - 1]["months"] });
        }
        i++;
    }
    return test;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) (https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-reverse) or [undercore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or just use native [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So we got it working excactly how we wanted and an updated fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/guideveloper/whasgrfL/7/

```
function fillArray(arr) {
    var i = 1;
    while (i < test.length) {
        if ((test[i]["percentage"] * 1 - test[i - 1]["percentage"] * 1) > 1) {
            test.splice(i, 0, { 
              "percentage": test[i-1].percentage+1,
              "factor": test[i]["factor"],
              "upperMonths": test[i]["upperMonths"],
              "lowerMonths": test[i]["lowerMonths"],
              "limit": test[i]["limit"],
               "months": test[i]["months"] });
        }
        i++;
    }
    return test;
}
```